# How can I use a key.pem file in Netsuite to sign a HTTP request with Suitescript?

Tags: api, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am trying to sign a https request and for that I need to encrypt a digest. From the api I generated both a certificate.pem and a privateKey.pem. I uploaded them both in Netsuite in the Certficate and Key part of the company set up.

My question is mainly how do I now get the privateKey from the file to use with the crypto module?

Here is what I have so far. 
"payload" is the data I want to encrypt for my digest and is just a string.

```
var sKey = keyControl.loadKey('custkey2');
var hmacObj = crypto.createHmac({
                    algorithm: crypto.HashAlg.SHA256,
                    key: sKey
                });
var updatedHmac = hmacObj.update({
                    input: payload,
                    inputEncoding:encode.Encoding.UTF_8
                });
var reencoded = encode.convert({
                    string: updatedHmac,
                    inputEncoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8,
                    outputEncoding: encode.Encoding.BASE_64
                });
```

But when ever I run that in my Suitelet I get an error coming from the "create Hmac".
any help would be more than appreciated thank you.

Comment: If you share the error message that would probably help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SS2.0 module `N/https/clientCertificate` holds the answer. Instead of using `https.post()` use `clientCertificate.post()` which can send SSL requests with a digital certificate.

Example that works for me:

```
/* 1st create certificate in NetSuite UI (Setup > Pereferences > Certificates) */
const certId = 'custcertificate_xy';
/* 2nd use certificates id inside request call */
const response = clientCertificate.post({
   url: url,
   body: body,
   certId: certId,
   headers: headers
});
```

Please note that for some reason NetSuite wanted me to have certificate (*.pem) file in following format:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
      {{private key}}
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      {{certificate}}
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Where did you find this format? Pfx file doesn't work? @martin